# Can Morgana cast other abilities during Soul Shackles' tether?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can Morgana cast other abilities, her Q, W and E, while the Soul Shackles (R) tether is in place?

Comment: Why would she not be able to? Tethers in general are neither channelled nor cast spells, nor do they self-silence (like Rumble's passive). Any time you have a tether on someone, you can still move and cast spells normally (unless, of course, you've been CC'ed by another spell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, Yes. Definitly a good idea to ult then root your enemy.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, yes she can.

Morgana can cast abilities and use items such as zhonya's hourglass during the tethering of Soul Shackles

Answer (score 1):

Morgana definitely can use her other abilities with no restriction during her ultimate being in effect. Like 'hammy' said, her ultimate will stay up if she pops zhonyas, which is why it is a great survivability item for jumping for the initiation in big team fights for her.